# How to convert json to struct using goreq?

Tags: json, rest, go, struct

Using Go I'm trying to get some json from a server for which I'm using the [goreq library](https://github.com/franela/goreq/). When I print out the resulting string as follows:

```
s, _ := res.Body.ToString()
fmt.Println(s)
```

I get a correct json string:

```
{"success":true,"testnet":false,"message":"","result":{"btc":4014.16,"edp":4014.16},"msIn":1505820331492,"msOut":1505820331492}
```

So using [this json-to-go webservice](https://transform.now.sh/json-to-go/) I converted this json message to a struct:

```
type Index struct {
    Success bool   `json:"success"`
    Testnet bool   `json:"testnet"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Result  struct {
        Btc float64 `json:"btc"`
        Edp float64 `json:"edp"`
    } `json:"result"`
    MsIn  int64 `json:"msIn"`
    MsOut int64 `json:"msOut"`
}
```

and I use that as follows ([implementation of FromJsonTo() here](https://github.com/franela/goreq/blob/master/goreq.go#L117-L119)):

```
var item Index
res.Body.FromJsonTo(&item)
fmt.Println(item)
```

This just prints out the nulled Index struct though (while the json str is still the same):

```
{false false  {0 0} 0 0}
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps the body is empty..though it could be the object isn't being passed correctly by reference... You might want to go ahead and get the body's bytes and unmarshal into your struct yourself... or test that you can unmarshal the raw bytes yourself.

Comment: `FromJsonTo()` returns an error, so you might try printing that out and see if goreq can give you more information about what's going on

Comment: Also looking at the git example.. 
https://github.com/franela/goreq/#user-content-receiving-json

They don't seem to be using json tags in their structs.

Comment: do you strictly needed goreq? if not, then there are other libraries that you might try like gorequest, https://github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `res.Body.ToString()` you read the whole body of the response. Next, when you call `res.Body.FromJsonTo()`, body is empty and therefore `EOF` error is returned. Removing `ToString()` from your code should help.

Comment: Awesome, that was it!